# Apply sourcemaps on local file system to minified production code in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

My production application is deployed without source maps.

Is there a way to take the generated source maps for the bundle in production, that I have on my local file system, and apply them to the minified code being served from our production server in Chrome DevTools?

Comment: Are you after troubleshooting a production issue (resolving a minified stack trace) or you just want to run prod code locally with source maps enabled?

Comment: Same difference I suppose, either or.